# Automated Ignite Cluster Snapshots: How to Generate Random Names?

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I'm working with an Ignite cluster, and I want to set up automated snapshots. The documentation provides instructions on creating snapshots with specific names, but since I'm running an automated script, I need these names to be random for each snapshot. How can I achieve this?

Is there a better approach to handling automated snapshots in an Ignite cluster?

Documentation Reference: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/snapshots/snapshots

Documentation Reference Command:

```
control.(sh|bat) --snapshot create snapshot_09062021
```

I appreciate any guidance or alternative solutions you can provide.

I tried to perform the automated backup using bash, through kubectl but as I can not pass a different name to the command, I could not solve

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a shell-scripting question than about Ignite. How about something like this:

```
control.sh --snapshot create snapshot_$(date -u "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```